# Eclipse errors after updates

Tags: eclipse

The Eclipse development environment stopped working after installing updates following Help > Check for updates.

All 8 projects and libraries show errors. Errors include:

```
The import Android cannot be resolved; 
SherlockActivity cannot be resolved to type; 
all Java statements cannot be resolved..
```

I tried to create a new Android application and the "Compile with" list item was empty so the project could not be created.  Also when saving a modified existing Java file, the system responds "Android Lint has encountered a problem".

Should I un-install Eclipse (prior to re-installing) and, if so, how (should I just delete the Eclipse  folder)? Should I just re-install Eclipse without uninstalling? I use recent Google API's for maps, Support V4 library and ActionbarSherlock library.

Or, is there was most selective solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Given it is an Android project, you probably updated the Eclipse plugin for Android but didn't update the Android SDK itself.

You can update the Android SDK inside Eclipse by going `Window- > Android SDK Manager`.